# How can I extract all repeated pattern in a line to comma separated format

Tags: unix, sed, grep, pattern-matching

I am extracting an interested pattern in a file. In each line I have repeated pattern and I want to order all repeated pattern for each line in a comma separated format. For example: In each line I have a string like this:

> Line1: InterPro:IPR000504 InterPro:IPR003954 InterPro:IPR012677 Pfam:PF00076 PROSITE:PS50102 SMART:SM00360 SMART:SM00361 EMBL:CP002684 Proteomes:UP000006548 GO:GO:0009507 GO:GO:0003723 GO:GO:0000166 Gene3D:3.30.70.330 SUPFAM:SSF54928 eggNOG:KOG0118 eggNOG:COG0724 InterPro:IPR003954
>
> Line2: InterPro:IPR000306 InterPro:IPR002423 InterPro:IPR002498 Pfam:PF00118 Pfam:PF01363 Pfam:PF01504 PROSITE:PS51455 SMART:SM00064 SMART:SM00330 InterPro:IPR013083 Proteomes:UP000006548 GO:GO:0005739 GO:GO:0005524 EMBL:CP002686 GO:GO:0009555 GO:GO:0046872 GO:GO:0005768 GO:GO:0010008 Gene3D:3.30.40.10 InterPro:IPR017455

I want to extract all InterPro IDs for each line as like as this :

> IPR000504,IPR003954,IPR012677,IPR003954
>
> IPR000306,IPR002423,IPR002498,IPR013083,IPR017455

I have used this script:

```
while read line; do
    NUM=$(echo $line | grep -oP 'InterPro:\K[^ ]+' | wc -l)
    if [ $NUM -eq 0 ];then
       echo "NA" >> InterPro.txt;
    fi; 
    if [ ! $NUM -eq 0 ];then
       echo $line | grep -oP 'InterPro:\K[^ ]+' | tr '\n' ',' >> InterPro.txt;
    fi;
done <./File.txt
```

The problem is once I run this script, all the pattern's values in the File.txt print in one line. I want all interested pattern's values of each line print in separated line.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {if ($i~/^InterPro:/) {gsub(/InterPro:/, "", $i); x=x","$i}} gsub (/^,/, "", x); print x; x=""}' file
```

Output:

```
IPR000504,IPR003954,IPR012677,IPR003954
IPR000306,IPR002423,IPR002498,IPR013083,IPR017455
```

---

With indent and more meaningful variable names:

```
awk '
{
  for (column=1; column<=NF; ++column) 
  {
    if ($column~/^InterPro:/) 
    {
      gsub(/InterPro:/, "", $column)
      line=line","$column
    }
  } 
  gsub (/^,/, "",line)
  print line
  line=""
}' file
```

---

With bash builtin commands:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do 
  for column in $line; do
    [[ $column =~ ^InterPro:(.*) ]] && new+=",${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  done
  echo "${new#,*}"
  unset new
done < file
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I changed the script and could get the interested results:

```
while read line; do
    NUM=$(echo $line | grep -oP 'InterPro:\K[^ ]+' | wc -l)
    if [ $NUM -eq 0 ];then
       echo "NA" >> InterPro.txt;
    fi; 
    if [ ! $NUM -eq 0 ];then
       echo $line | grep -oP 'InterPro:\K[^ ]+' | sed -n -e 'H;${x;s/\n/,/g;s/^,//;p;}' | sed 's/ /,/g'  >> InterPro.txt;
    fi;
done <./File.txt
```